# How to properly memcpy without overflow issues

Tags: c++, memcpy, buffer-overflow

In a legacy code I am getting buffer overflow errors in fortify audit.
Let me explain the issue here:
I have a function, say `foo(size_t len, unsigned char **buf)`  ,in this `foo` I am *memcopying* a string variable in *buf* as follows.

```
char temp[256];

sprintf(temp, "abcd%s",somefunct_string.c_str()); //so the string temp is variable length

memcpy(*buf, temp, temp.length());
```

in practical, the `temp.length()` is always `< len` *(which is buf alloted size)*. But fortify would give potential risk here.

how do i resolve this?

Comment: `memcpy(*buf, temp, temp.length());` does not compile. Post a [mcve].

Comment: `memcpy(*buf, temp, temp.length());` shouldn't compile since `temp` is not a pointer. If you did pass a pointer to `temp` then you'd be copying the `std::string` object and not the data it points to. That object's size is constant `sizeof(std::string)` and has no relation to the length of the data it contains.

Comment: You need to overally change the design to avoid raw pointers in the first place. Make the buffer a `std::vector` and use `std::ranges::copy(str, std::back_inserter(vec));` to transfer the data. when dealing with lower level C API, use the `data` and `size` member functions as parameters; Up until there, stick to no-pointer policy.

Comment: Made changes so it is similar to my code now.

Comment: The code still does not compile. An array has no length member

Comment: Why are you using that `temp` buffer in the first place? Why not `snprintf` directly to the buffer given? I.e. `snprintf(buf, len, "abcd%s", somefunct_string.c_str());` note the **`n`** in the `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the std::string::data() function to access the string via a pointer to the string.

```
memcpy(*buf, somefunct_string.data(), somefunct_string.size());
```

Also, memcpy_s() is available since C11.

```
memcpy_s(*buf, temp.length(), somefunct_string.data(), somefunct_string.size())
```

memcpy() and memcpy_s() are called when copying a sequence from one array to another array.  If the copy overlaps within the same array, memmove() or memmove_s() should be called.

Comment: this makes the code compile (though I assume the code not compiling is just a typo in the question) but doesn't address possible overflow of `buf` if the string is too long

Comment: memcpy_s is not an option for me as legacy code . changing the library files might chugg with compilation altogether.